# How to generate multiple gaussian plots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple gaussian plots that'll have same mean and std dev, meaning that when the first plot ends at 20, the second plot must start from 20 and end at 40 with the peak being at 30

```
mu = 10
sigma = 2
n = 2
x = np.linspace(0,n*20,n*20)
for i in range(0,n):
    pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x, n*mu, sigma)
    plt.plot(x, pdf)
```

but this gives me just one plot as Image
[image]

What i would like to generate is:

Desired output
[image]

Can someone please tell me the mistake that I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your two gaussians do not have the same means, since one is at 10 and the other at 30.

Second, you are actually creating one one gaussian, with mean at `n*mu=20`. If you need to generate multiple gaussians, you'll have to call `norm.pdf` several times, e.g. in a loop:

```
mus = [10,30]
sigmas = [2,2]
x = np.linspace(0,40,100)
pdf = np.zeros(shape=x.shape)
for m,s in zip(mus,sigmas):
    pdf += stats.norm.pdf(x, m, s)
plt.plot(x, pdf)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that here:

```
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x, n*mu, sigma)
```

you are having the same `pdf` being plotted as `n` does not change inside the `loop`, you probably want to use `i` instead of `n`.
Except that it would not work because `i` takes value `0` and `1` and hence `mu` gets to be `0` and `20` and you would need to fix also that.
For a generally cleaner approach have a look at the other answer.