# Problem in plotting n gaussian curves for n consecutive days

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, logic, gaussian

I am trying to plot n gaussian curves for n consecutive days. The plot must start at the `base` value inputted by the user, reach the `peak` value at 46800secs (13:00 or 1pm) and again end at the nearly about the `base` value at the end of the day and again for the next n days, the same curve must be replicated. I am following the suggestion from this post: [Generating multiple gaussian plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321994/how-to-generate-multiple-gaussian-plots)

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
from datetime import datetime

def date_inputs(start_date, end_date):
    try:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq = 'S').tolist()
        dates = pd.Series(dates)
        dates_diff = abs((end_date - start_date).days)
        dates = dates.iloc[:-1]
        print('Dates accepted!')
        return dates, dates_diff
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect date format, should be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")

start_date_input = str(input('Enter start date in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format: '))
end_date_input = str(input('Enter end date in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format: '))
dates, n = date_inputs(start_date_input, end_date_input)

def bell_curve(total_consumption, peak, base, n):
    x = np.linspace(0, n*86400, n*86400)
    sigma = total_consumption/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*(peak-base))
    sigmas = [sigma]*n
    pdf_value = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for m, s in zip(mus, sigmas):
        pdf_value += stats.norm.pdf(x,m,s)
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
    plt.plot(dates, (total_consumption*pdf_value) + base)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 70)
    plt.show()
    return pdf_value

mu = 46800
seconds_in_one_day = 86400
mus = []
for i in range(0,n):
    mus.append(mu+(i*seconds_in_one_day))


peak = float(input('Enter the peak value in Watts:'))
total_consumption = float(input('Enter the total consumption in one day in Watts:'))
base = float(input('Enter the base value in Watts:'))

pdf_values = bell_curve(total_consumption, peak, base, n)
```

When I give the inputs as follows:

`start_day: 2018-01-01 00:00:00`, `end_day: 2018-01-02 00:00:00` with `peak` as 2222, `base` as 500 & `total_consumption` as 630000000, I get the following graph:

**Figure 1**
[image]

The above graph is for one day and it is correct.

When I change the end date to `end_day: 2018-01-03 00:00:00` the difference between the start & end date is 2, so I want 2 same graphs to be plotted side by side with the same peak value, same base value and the peak occuring at 13:00 or 1pm the next day too:

**Figure 2: Example how the gaussian curves for 2 days must look like**
[image]

But instead of looking like figure 2, the graph looks as follows:

**Figure 3**
[image]

In the figure 3, we can see that instead of 2 graphs, one graph is being plotted with the peak and base values being completely wrong.

Can someone please tell me what is the mistake I am doing with my code here?

Thanks

Comment: you have it normalizing the 2 day range. when you normalize a graph the area under the curve has to be equal to one.

Comment: Hey @AnnaNevison, can you please show where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `sigma` value is too large. I don't know what you are trying to calculate, so I cannot help you on how to calculate that value, but here is the output of your code when manually changing the value in `bell_curve()` to `sigma = 10000`:

[image]